# Add ability to increase font size for android app

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, android-app

I have a hard time reading questions and answer on Stack Exchange sites sometimes.

I hate having to bring my phone or laptop very close to my face to read things sometimes.

I would love if there was an option to increase the font size in the app. Can this please be done?

Comment: +1 here, as my [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329656/font-size-selection-on-se-android-app) was marked as a duplicate of this one. The comments text is particularly tiny, looks like it does not follow the system font enlargement.