# Font size selection on SE android app?

Tags: feature-request, android-app

I apologize if this has been asked many times before but I just cannot find where to adjust the font size in the app (ver. 1.0.95). It would be very surprising if such feature were simply not available but I can't find it for the life of me.

Upd.: Hmm, found other similar requests. Indeed, the feature seems to be not there. it is **highly desireable**, on an 8'' Tablet the font is very small.